# How to inner join 4 tables in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, orm

We want to retrieve all table records at a time how to implement like SQL queries in django orm.

Example SQL query:

```
select * 
from Company_info 
inner join Bank_info on Bank_info.manufacturer = Company_info.manufacturer
inner join Company_info on Company_info.manufacturer = Company_info.manufacturer
inner join Transport_info on Transport_info.manufacturer = Company_info.manufacturer
```

Code:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=42)

class Bank_info(models.Model):
    account = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

class Company_info(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=42)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

class Transport_info(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=42)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: add related name in models 2, 3 and 4 in FoeignKey field and use this. Manufacturer.objects.all().prefetch_related('related_name2', 'related_name3', 'related_name4').

Comment: thank you it's working great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for this, as mentioned in comments:

```
Manufacturer.objects.all().prefetch_related('related_name2', 'related_name3', 'related_name4')
```

This, in fact, will not perform an SQL INNER JOIN, but will join prefetched objects on Python level - this will decrease hits to DB when using related object fields.